# Image won't stretch container width

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I'm having trouble getting an image to stretch the entire width of a containing element.  The page layout is two-column fluid responsive.  Main content is contained in the left column, whereas "extra" stuff is contained in the right hand column.  I created a 400x400 image that I want to appear in the topmost right sidebar (`class = "top-sidebar"`).  I cannot for the life of me get the image to fit its width to the width of the top sidebar.  Here are my code snippets:

The HTML:

```
<aside class="top-sidebar">
        <article>
            <p><img src="images/callustoday.jpg" alt="Call us today at 716-200-7397 to start training!"/></p>
        </article>
    </aside>
```

The corresponding CSS:

```
.top-sidebar {
    width: 22%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 2% 0 0 2%;
    padding: 0;
}

.top-sidebar img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

To add to the frustration, I can't even seem to get the image to center within its parent container using `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the latter part: 
Using `margin: auto` only works for centering, if the block-element to which you apply the style has a defined width, given in pixel. E.g., if you would specify a width of 300px for your image it would be centered. Since this is not an option i suggest a different approach:

How about putting the image as a `background-image` on the `article` tag?
That way, you can center the image by using `background-position: center` and make it span the whole width by using `background-size: cover`

A solution can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c6rq3/)

HTML:

```
<aside class="top-sidebar">
    <article class="callustoday">
    </article>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
.callustoday{
    background-image: url("yourimage.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.top-sidebar {
    width: 22%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 2% 0 0 2%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I set the `img` as a `background-image` on the `article` and it did not even appear.  Interestingly, I also tried setting the `img` to a fixed pixel width.  It still would not center within its containing element.  I'm wondering if there might be something weird going on with the actual dimensions of the containing element which would cause it to only span around 80% of the sidebar width.

Comment: added possible implementation

Answer (score 1):

```
.callustoday {
    background-image: url(yourimage.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You should chuck a `border: 1px red solid;` to see how big the box is that contains the image, too; that way, you can always see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to scale images using the browser like that as it tends either to create extra overhead (unnecessarily large file size/resolution), or a bad user experience (pixelated low res image due to upscaling or incorrect aspect ratio).

That being said, you are only setting the `max-width` of `img` in your CSS. Have you tried setting the `width: 100%` too? If that doesn't work on its own, also try adding `float: left;` to `.top-sidebar img`

Comment: I have tried width: 100% and float: left to the img to no avail.  If I had more rep points I could post an image of what the actual problem looks like, but basically the image fills only 80% of the actual column width (even when the column is much smaller than its original px width).

Comment: Your `img` tag is inside a `<p>` tag, could the paragraph element have margins/padding which are affecting the image's maximum size?

Comment: I got rid of the `<p>` tag and there was no effect on the `img` dimensions.